# Need R function for comparing missing values in one file and update in another file

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have 3 csv files which are read as df.

```
df1 - 

Code Number 
A     12
B     13
C     14 
D     15
E     16
F     17
G     18
```

df2 contains just code. These codes are mandatory codes and must be present in df1. If any code in df2 is missing in df1 then it should be added to df1 and its corresponding "Number" column should be updated from df3.

```
dF2 - 
Code 
A
B
C
X
```

Here X from df2 is missing. So it should be added to df1 and its number should be pulled from df3.

```
df3
Code Number 
A     22
B     34
C     56 
D     78
X     99
Y     100
```

Output -

```
df1 - 

Code Number 
A     12
B     13
C     14 
D     15
E     16
F     17
G     18
X     99
```

I have code which is working fine for to satisfy this conditions.

However i want everything to be done via a function.

My function should do something like this -

```
If any code present in df2 is missing in df1 then
{
i) get that code from df2
ii) get the number for that code from df3

iii) append that code and number to df1.

} else {
  df1<-df1 

}
```

Below is my code which is working fine.

```
df4<-merge(df2, df1, by = "code", all = T)

library(dplyr)

df5<-df4 %>%
  left_join(df3, by = c("code")) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(count.x), count.y, count.x)) %>%
  select(-c(count.x, count.y))

df1<-df5
```

Issues with above code -

1) It is updating df1 every time even though codes are missing are not. which is fine but i think it can be improved. I don't want code to update df1 if any code from df2 is not missing in df1.
2)I want everything to be done via a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't need a loop to do this task. A faster way is to use merge functions like shown below:

```
# sample data
df1 <- data.table(code=c('A','B','C'), Number=c(10,20,30))
df2 <- data.table(code =  c('A','B','X'))
df3 <- data.table(code=c('A','X','C'), Number=c(10,200,30))

# join df1 and df2 - full join
df_temp <- merge(df1, df2, by = "code", all = TRUE)

# join again df1 and df3 - full join
df4 <- merge(df_temp, df3, by = "code", all = TRUE)

# fill missing value

fill_values <- function(x){

  if(is.na(x['Number.x'])) return(x['Number.y'])
  else return (x['Number.x'])

}

df4$Number <- apply(df4, 1, fill_values)

# select final columns
df4 <- df4[,c('code','Number'),with=F]
print(df4)

   code Number
1:    A     10
2:    B     20
3:    C     30
4:    X    200
```

Comment: This code is working fine. but its inserting all codes and their values from df3 into df1 I want the codes from df2  that are missing in df1 should be inserted and their number should be picked up from df3.